# Add numeric p-value to gam summary table using flextable

Tags: r, summary, gam, flextable

I'm just trying to print a nice table using the `flextable` package. In general `flextable` works very well, but I need to add a numeric **p-value** next to the asterisk symbols for significance. `Flextable` do that automatically for linear models, but it seems that don't do the same for GAM models.

I'm using the `mgcv` package for gam, and this is what I'm doing:

```r
ab<-gamSim(eg=1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2,verbose=TRUE)
 
gam_ab<-gam(y~x0+x1+x2, data=ab)
 
summary(gam_ab)
 
as_flextable(gam_ab)
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Is there any way to add this numerical value in this column for GAM summary tables using `flextable`? or, is there another easy way to do nice tables for GAM summary?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: your code is not in your question, can you edit your question and add it in?

Comment: Sorry, it's a bug. I think I fixed it (only in the dev version on github for now)